# Online database of formulae for series, infinite products, limits, ecc.

Tags: closed-form, online-resources

Around the site there are *a lot* of questions about closed form expressions or approximations for specific series, products, limits and whatnot.
These however are hard to find to the difficulty in searching for specific formulas.

Is there some resource online with a discretely comprehensive list of formulas, with proofs of the results, and organized in such a way to be easily accessible?

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, you can simply start an appropriate MSE-question with the tag (big-list).

Comment: @GitGud would that be compatible with the policies on math.se then? Or would such a list be better off in the tag wiki?

Comment: My opinion is that it is an appropriate question. If with 'tag wiki' you mean community wiki, I do not know. Don't make it CW, moderators will do if they see fit.

Comment: @GitGud no, I mean the [tag wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/infinite-product/info)

Comment: @glance The tag wiki is no place for formulas, it's there to describe how the tag is to be used, when it is to be applied and what other tags may be better suited.

Comment: @AlexR if that is how you use it I don't object it of course. But tag wiki pages *are* used e.g. in stackoverflow to link to the most relevant questions of the tag and diplay other useful info. See e.g. the [c++ tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info).

Comment: @glance Over here this is not usual, but this means your question belongs to [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com). Voting to migrate. You should try to re-phrase the question to make it clear what you are suggesting (include the link to SO's c++ tag wiki for example).

Comment: @AlexR actually, the question was primarily asking for the existence of other online resources. The meta discussion in the comments is parallel but not coincident to the question (so maybe is these comments that are off-topic here). I'll remove the part about such a list here on math.se and eventually ask it on meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the closest you come is with the NIST digital library of mathematical functions:
http://dlmf.nist.gov/                 which is destined to eventually replace the classic
Abramowitz & Stegun: "Handbook of Mathematical Functions: with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables (Dover Books on Mathematics)".

If google could only make a specialized search engine for mathematical expressions ...